# Magento 2 : how to add row url title in grid

Tags: magento2, grid

Is there any way to add title on **getRowUrl** in **grid magento2**. Below is my code

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', ['id' => $row->getId()]);
    }
```

Comment: Please check `getUrl` function & Add Title means Example? `<a href="" title=""`?

Comment: i don't think this is concern with `getUrl`. yes this is i want.

Comment: Can you give example what kind of output u need?

Comment: as it mention in you example `<a href="" title="want to add here">`

Comment: `return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', ['id' => $row->getId(), 'title' => 'test']);`  Works?

Comment: @AnkitShah tried that but not worked

Comment: No choice. U need to override that function as per your need. That's it

Comment: this function `$this->getUrl` creating the url not **html** part

Comment: That i know @Qaisar